# Fitting data to a Markov Chain

Tags: time-series, goodness-of-fit, markov-process

I am looking for the reference/toolbox/note on how to fit a finite discrete-time Markov Chain to given time series. Ideally, there shall also be criteria of whether the fit is good, and whether additional levels of history-dependence are needed to be added. Of course, I can simply count how many times each state appeared, and how many times it led to a given successor state to estimated the transition probability matrix, however I believe that such naive method is not the best one.

Comment: In a finite state-space discrete-time setting, there is not much of a difference between fitting a Markov chain and fitting a multinomial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a single Markov chain [Minka (2003)](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/papers/minka-multinomial.pdf) provides a Bayesian treatment.

From the top of my head, you could use the results in that paper to calculate the log likelihood of first and second order models and use a Bayes factor to make the decision.